# Why concatenate GUI Containers?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I just want to know , why we use to much Containers ? i mean,for example this project find it in youtube , he uses a lot of Containers ? he can use only one Container right ? not containers within containers within containers ??...
[image]
i just want to know why we use containers within containers within containers..

The FXML Code :

```xml
<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
  fx:controller="controller.daftarBajuController">
  <children>
    <AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" fx:id="loadBaju" prefHeight="650.0"
      prefWidth="1000.0"
      style="-fx-background-color: white; -fx-background-image: url(&quot;/gambar/grid.jpg&quot;);"
      AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0"
      AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
      <children>
        <StackPane fx:id="tambahBaju" prefHeight="650.0"
          prefWidth="1000.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0"
          AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0"
          AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
          <children>
            <Group>
              <children>
                <StackPane fx:id="loadStage" layoutX="347.0" layoutY="182.0"
                  prefHeight="287.0" prefWidth="306.0"
                  style="-fx-background-color: white; -fx-background-radius: 10; -fx-padding: 10; -fx-effect: dropshadow(three-pass-box, rgba(0,0,0,0.8), 10, 0, 0, 0);"
                  AnchorPane.leftAnchor="358.0" />
                <Button layoutX="642.0" layoutY="173.0" mnemonicParsing="false"
                  onAction="#btnClose" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="21.0"
                  style="-fx-background-image: url(&quot;/gambar/closePage.png&quot;); -fx-background-size: 100% 100%;">
                  <font>
                    <Font size="8.0" />
                  </font>
                </Button>
              </children>
            </Group>
          </children>
        </StackPane>
        <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.18454935622317598"
          focusTraversable="true" orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="633.0"
          prefWidth="1000.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0"
          AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0"
          AnchorPane.topAnchor="17.0">
          <items>
            <AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity"
              prefHeight="124.0" prefWidth="998.0"
              style="-fx-background-image: url(&quot;/gambar/header.gif&quot;); -fx-background-size: 100% 100%;"
              SplitPane.resizableWithParent="false">
              <children>
                <Label layoutX="30.0" layoutY="42.0" text="Example JavaFX"
                  textFill="#046272">
                  <font>
                    <Font name="Gill Sans MT" size="40.0" />
                  </font>
                  <effect>
                    <Reflection topOpacity="0.2" />
                  </effect>
                </Label>
                <HBox layoutX="803.0" layoutY="70.0" spacing="10.0"
                  AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="26.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="130.0"
                  AnchorPane.topAnchor="70.0">
                  <children>
                    <Label layoutX="803.0" layoutY="70.0" text="Login By  :"
                      AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="26.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="140.0"
                      AnchorPane.topAnchor="70.0">
                      <font>
                        <Font size="14.0" />
                      </font>
                    </Label>
                    <Label fx:id="lblAdmin" layoutX="872.0" layoutY="71.0"
                      AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="26.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="70.0">
                      <font>
                        <Font size="14.0" />
                      </font>
                    </Label>
                  </children>
                </HBox>
              </children>
            </AnchorPane>
            <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="418.0"
              prefWidth="676.0">
              <children>
                <AnchorPane fx:id="editBaju" layoutX="179.0" layoutY="63.0"
                  prefHeight="316.0" prefWidth="336.0" />
                <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.23393574297188754"
                  focusTraversable="true" layoutX="602.0" layoutY="48.0"
                  prefHeight="525.0" prefWidth="998.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0"
                  AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0"
                  AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                  <items>
                    <AnchorPane maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="0.0"
                      minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="230.0"
                      style="-fx-background-color: white;"
                      SplitPane.resizableWithParent="false">
                      <children>
                        <Accordion prefHeight="305.0" prefWidth="230.0"
                          AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="205.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0"
                          AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                          <panes>
                            <TitledPane text="Menu">
                              <content>
                                <StackPane>
                                  <children>
                                    <ListView fx:id="listViewBaju" layoutX="-2.0"
                                      onMouseClicked="#klikListDaftar" prefHeight="190.0"
                                      prefWidth="236.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="23.0"
                                      AnchorPane.topAnchor="5.0" StackPane.alignment="CENTER">
                                      <StackPane.margin>
                                        <Insets bottom="-11.0" left="-12.0" right="-11.0"
                                          top="-11.0" />
                                      </StackPane.margin>
                                    </ListView>
                                  </children>
                                </StackPane>
                              </content>
                            </TitledPane>
                            <TitledPane text="Transaksi">
                              <content>
                                <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0"
                                  prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
                              </content>
                            </TitledPane>
                            <TitledPane text="Laporan">
                              <content>
                                <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0"
                                  prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
                              </content>
                            </TitledPane>
                          </panes>
                        </Accordion>
                      </children>
                    </AnchorPane>
                    <StackPane>
                      <children>
                        <StackPane fx:id="daftarListMenu" opacity="0.0"
                          prefHeight="150.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
                        <StackPane fx:id="menuBaju" style="-fx-background-color: white;"
                          StackPane.alignment="CENTER">
                          <children>
                            <Group layoutX="52.0" layoutY="67.0"
                              StackPane.alignment="CENTER">
                              <children>
                                <TableView fx:id="tableBaju" layoutX="32.0"
                                  layoutY="2.0" onMouseClicked="#klikBaju" prefHeight="324.0"
                                  prefWidth="666.0"
                                  stylesheets="file:/D:/javafx/daftarHargaBaju/src/css/baju.css">
                                  <columns>
                                    <TableColumn fx:id="colNo" minWidth="0.0"
                                      prefWidth="0.0" resizable="false" text="No" />
                                    <TableColumn fx:id="colKode" prefWidth="73.0"
                                      resizable="false" text="Kode" />
                                    <TableColumn fx:id="colNama" prefWidth="142.0"
                                      text="Nama Baju" />
                                    <TableColumn fx:id="colVendor" prefWidth="142.0"
                                      text="Vendor Baju" />
                                    <TableColumn fx:id="colHarga" prefWidth="138.0"
                                      text="Harga Baju" />
                                    <TableColumn fx:id="colTanggal" prefWidth="152.0"
                                      text="Tanggal" />
                                  </columns>
                                </TableView>
                                <HBox layoutX="34.0" layoutY="346.0" spacing="10.0">
                                  <children>
                                    <Button layoutX="34.0" layoutY="366.0"
                                      mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btnTambah"
                                      prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="74.0" style="-fx-text-fill: white;"
                                      styleClass="custem-button-input"
                                      stylesheets="file:/D:/javafx/daftarHargaBaju/src/css/baju.css"
                                      text="Tambah">
                                      <font>
                                        <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" />
                                      </font>
                                    </Button>
                                    <Button layoutX="149.0" layoutY="366.0"
                                      mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btnEdit"
                                      prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="74.0" style="-fx-text-fill: white;"
                                      styleClass="custem-button-input"
                                      stylesheets="file:/D:/javafx/daftarHargaBaju/src/css/baju.css"
                                      text="Edit">
                                      <font>
                                        <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" />
                                      </font>
                                    </Button>
                                    <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btnBatal"
                                      prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="74.0" style="-fx-text-fill: white;"
                                      styleClass="custem-button-input"
                                      stylesheets="file:/D:/javafx/daftarHargaBaju/src/css/baju.css"
                                      text="Refresh">
                                      <font>
                                        <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" />
                                      </font>
                                    </Button>
                                    <Button layoutX="265.0" layoutY="366.0"
                                      mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btnHapus"
                                      prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="74.0" style="-fx-text-fill: white;"
                                      styleClass="custem-button-input"
                                      stylesheets="file:/D:/javafx/daftarHargaBaju/src/css/baju.css"
                                      text="Hapus">
                                      <font>
                                        <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" />
                                      </font>
                                    </Button>
                                  </children>
                                </HBox>
                                <TextField fx:id="txtCariBaju" layoutX="418.0"
                                  layoutY="349.0" onKeyReleased="#cariBaju" prefHeight="25.0"
                                  prefWidth="280.0" promptText="Pencarian" />
                                <Region layoutX="34.0" layoutY="-14.0"
                                  prefHeight="16.0" prefWidth="677.0" />
                                <Region layoutX="20.0" layoutY="2.0" prefHeight="386.0"
                                  prefWidth="12.0" />
                              </children>
                              <StackPane.margin>
                                <Insets bottom="4.0" left="4.0" right="4.0" top="4.0" />
                              </StackPane.margin>
                            </Group>
                          </children>
                        </StackPane>
                      </children>
                    </StackPane>
                  </items>
                </SplitPane>
              </children>
            </AnchorPane>
          </items>
        </SplitPane>
      </children>
    </AnchorPane>
    <MenuBar prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="1000.0"
      AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0"
      AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
      <menus>
        <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
          <items>
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
          </items>
        </Menu>
        <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
          <items>
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
          </items>
        </Menu>
        <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
          <items>
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
          </items>
        </Menu>
      </menus>
      <effect>
        <DropShadow />
      </effect>
    </MenuBar>
  </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: So you would prefer to write much code instead (probably >2000K LOC) that you can't reuse except under very specific circumstances?

Comment: Which containers there do you think are redundant? How else would you create this layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That usually make it easier to move/process as your components are in groups.

And in some way, it's more logical and similar to the physical world.

Let's say bold words are containers and italics are components (and bold italic word are... containers and component). Now if you try to describe a ***bookshelf***: it' in a ***house***, in a ***room***, on a ***side***, it has multiple shelves and each ***shelf*** contains some *books* or *stuff*. 
And each one is normally put relatively to its container.

If you wan to locate a book, it's in the bookshelf.
If you want to move the bookshelf, each components contained will be moved simultaneously. That sounds pretty obvious, right?

Of course, it's possible to use less containers. We saw a ***room*** contains **books**. They are in the same spot as before but we decide they are not in the bookshelf container any more.

The room still contains books. They still are at the same location and they still behave like books.

Will it sound right if, when you attempt to move the bookshelf, books and stuff stay floating in the air at their old location?
Well, that's probably what would happen if you don't use those containers.